# Problema ao popular uma ListView

Tags: android, sqlite

Preciso popular uma `ListView` que está usando um adaptador customizado no meu aplicativo mas nada acontece, a lista simplesmente fica em branco.

Eis o adaptador:

```
package adapters;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import br.bravosix.compromissos.R;
import classes.Event;

public class EventListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<Event> events;

    public EventListAdapter(Context context, List<Event> events) {
        super(context, R.layout.event_layout);
        this.context = context;
        this.events = events;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_layout, parent, false);

        TextView titleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        TextView descText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);

        Event event = new Event();
        event = events.get(position);

        titleText.setText(event.toString());
        descText.setText(event.getDescription());
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Essa é a função usada para popular o `ListView`:

```
public void loadEvents() {
    Database db = new Database(getActivity());
    EventListAdapter listEvents = new EventListAdapter(getActivity(),
            db.readEvents());
    setListAdapter(listEvents);
}
```

E, por fim, essa é a função que lê os eventos de dentro do BD:

```
public List<Event> readEvents() {

    List<Event> events = new LinkedList<Event>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + table_event + " WHERE user_id="
            + SingletonUser.getInstance().getId()
            + " ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Event event = null;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            event = new Event();
            event.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            event.setUserId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            event.setName(cursor.getString(2));
            event.setPlace(cursor.getString(3));
            event.setDate(cursor.getString(4));
            event.setContact(cursor.getString(5));
            event.setNotes(cursor.getString(6));

            events.add(event);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return events;
}
```

Estou definindo o ID do usuário dentro de uma `Singleton` para que ele possa ser acessível de qualquer parte do código usando esta função:

```
public int getUserId(String email) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT ? FROM " + table_user
            + " WHERE email=?", new String[] { "id", email });

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int count = cursor.getCount();

    if (count < 0) {
        return -1;

    } else {
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }
}
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Já experimentaste ver o tamanho da lista events para ver se lá estão? Poderá ser um erro de SQL.

Comment: Creio que o problema não seja erro de SQLite pois ele não retorna nenhuma informação de erro no logcat. No caso, eu reparei que a minha função para retornar o ID do usuário está me retornando 0 (no caso do usuário de testes), ao invés de 1, como deveria ser o primeiro ID do BD. Saberia me dizer por que isso acontece? Ainda não me fez sentido.

Comment: `new String[] { "id", email }` não faltam aspas no email?

Comment: Não, pois o `email` é uma `String` passada como variável da função: `public int getUserId(String email)`

Comment: Faz um `select *` a ver o que te retorna.

Comment: Fazendo um `select *` me retornou o valor correto, porém ainda não está funcionando. Ele cadastra corretamente no BD o evento (ou melhor, não gera mensagem de erro ao fazer o mesmo), a `Singleton` está recebendo o valor do ID do usuário, mas na hora de recuperar esses dados ou nada é retornado ou há algo de errado com meu adaptador.

Comment: Faz um `Log.e("Singleton", SingletonUser.getInstance().getId()+"");` no inicio de `readEvents()` e vê o que dá.

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14352/discussion-between-gh0st-h4wk-and-jorge-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muito trabalho, consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

1.Primeiro alterei a query da função `getUserId` de:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT ? FROM " + table_user
        + " WHERE email=?", new String[] { "id", email });
```

para:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table_user
                + " WHERE email=?", new String[] { email });
```

Somente assim consegui recuperar o ID do usuário de maneira correta.

2.Movi a função `loadEvents()` para dentro do método `onActivityCreated`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    loadEvents();
}
```

Fazendo isso, eu garanti que a lista só iria ser populada após o conteúdo da tela ter sido criado (sem isso deu um force close)

3.Corrigi a declaração do `EventListAdapter`, antes era:

```
public class EventListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<Event> events;

    public EventListAdapter(Context context, List<Event> events) {
        super(context, R.layout.event_layout);
        this.context = context;
        this.events = events;
    }
```

e passou a ser:

```
public class EventListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<Event> events;

    public EventListAdapter(Context context, List<Event> events) {
        super(context, R.layout.event_layout, events);
        this.context = context;
        this.events = events;
    }
```

Após isso consegui popular a ListView corretamente.